# Check if remote file exist and perform some other operation in expect script

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, tcl, expect

I am trying to write an expect script in Linux which needs to do following job.

- Login to remote windows machine using ssh
- Check if a certain file exists
- Compare timestamp of another file on the same path and print if it is newer

In step 1, I am trying to send one command to check if file exist but it does not work

```
log_user 1
spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $username@$hostname
expect {
..... user and password checks
.....
send "IF EXIST C:\\path\\to\\file\\temp.zip (echo FOUND) else (echo NOTFOUND)\r"
expect "path" {
   set result $expect_out(buffer)
   puts $result

   if{$result=="FOUND"} {
       #compare with temp2.zip here
   }
}
```

The result always contain the command I am sending not the output FOUND or NOTFOUND. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm feel like the Windows, bash, and batch-file tags don't belong here, but I don't know enough about what you're asking to be certain.

Comment: Unless you are talking to an old Mac (up to Mac OS 9), sending `\r` is usually wrong.

Comment: @somethingdark I am using expect script to execute windows commands on remote server

Comment: @IInspectable I used \n as well.. but \r working good in other scripts. So continued with it.

Comment: @IInspectable - Windows uses `r\n` as its newline.

Comment: @IInspectable, expect uses `\r` (carriage return) to represent "hitting enter"

Comment: @Nagarjun, this is one of the annoying things about expect: you have to parse out the command you sent to extract the results. Also, be careful with your syntax: Expect and Tcl, like sh/bash, parses commands and arguments using whitespace, so you need a space between `if` and `{` (see the [complete Tcl syntax](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using pattern matching your script tries to process the buffer manually but makes the incorrect assumption that the buffer will only contain the text "(NOT)FOUND". The buffer will actually contain everything received since the last time the command `expect` was used. Even if it did match the buffer correctly (e.g., with `string match *NOTFOUND* $result`), however, it would be affected by [the echo problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/2dsmYVtCn1c): the strings "FOUND" and "NOTFOUND" are in the command you send, which is most likely echoed back to you by the SSH server.

The following modification of the script hacks around the echo problem by not sending the literal strings it expects.

It works for me with the Bitvise SSH Server on the Windows side.

```
log_user 1
spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $username@$hostname
# Log in here.
send "set prefix=___\r" ;# Combat the echo problem.
send "IF EXIST C:\\path\\to\\file\\temp.zip (echo %prefix%FOUND) else (echo %prefix%NOTFOUND)\r"
expect {
    ___NOTFOUND {
        error {file not found}
    }
    ___FOUND {
        send_user Found!\n
        # Do things with the file.
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, you hit the bullseye. I was missing the echo problem here :-)